# How to edit a ggpattern legend in a bar plot with more than one legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggpattern

How can I edit the legend for the patterns while leaving the other legend as is when using ggpatterns?

I have the following plot:
[image: plot1]

I used the following code to make this plot:

```
ggplot(try2, aes(Season, prey_frq, fill=PreyName, pattern = Type)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(stat = "identity",
                   pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_color = "black",
                   pattern_angle = 45,
                   pattern_density = 0.04,
                   pattern_spacing = 0.04,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) +
  geom_text(data = subset(try2, prey_frq>3),
            aes(y = pos_label,
                label = PreyName), face = "bold", size = 7) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values = list,
                       c('Other' = 'none', 'Pelagic' = 'stripe', 'Benthic' = 'circle')) +
  ggtitle("TITLE") +
  labs(x="Season", fill = "Prey Name", y = "Prey Biomass Consumed (%)") + 
  scale_fill_igv(palette = "default") +
  guides(pattern = guide_legend(
    title = "Type",
    #direction = "horizontal",
    title.position = "top",
    label.position = "right",
    label.hjust = 0.5,
    label.vjust = 1
    #label.theme = element_text(angle = 90)
    , override.aes = list(fill = "white"), order = 2),
    fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none", order = 1))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face = "bold", family = "Arial",
                                  size=15),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = 1),
        legend.title.align = 0.5,
        legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15, 
                                    margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0), 
                                    color = "black"),
        axis.title.x.top = element_text(size = 14, 
                                        margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 10, l = 0), 
                                        color = "black"),
        text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, 
                                   angle = 0, 
                                   vjust = 0.5, 
                                   hjust = 1,
                                   margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, 
                                   angle = 0, 
                                   vjust = 1.5, 
                                   hjust = 0.5,
                                   margin = margin(t = 5, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14,
                                    face = "bold"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0.2,"cm")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0.01)))
```

My data:

```
structure(list(Season = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("Pre-Hypoxic", "Peak-Hypoxic", "Post-Hypoxic"), class = "factor"), PreyName = structure(c(1L,  2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 17L,  18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 18L,  1L, 2L, 7L, 10L, 12L, 15L, 17L), levels = c("Bythotrephes", "Chironomid Pupae",  "Copepod", "Cyclopoid", "Daphnia", "Amphipod", "Chironomid Larvae",  "Chydorid", "Dreissena", "Goby", "Hemimysis", "Isopod", "Sphaeriidae",  "Trichopteran", "Eurycercidae", "Chironomid Adult", "Chironomid",  "Egg Mass", "Fish Eggs", "Unidentified Prey Fish"), class = "factor"), 
    prey_tot = c(17.227374302, 18.112509605, 0.04050358, 0.005066528, 
    5.523993801, 2.136988844, 3.658250957, 0.002595249, 3.058675062, 
    1.450201253, 0.390600742, 0.012119854, 0.000132338, 3.25891984, 
    2.364342323, 0.144497136, 0.843162564, 0.770066004, 10.507750454, 
    2.35437128, 1, 3.701960013, 4.425697495, 2.716899247, 1.85298377, 
    0.005729159, 0.125721411, 0.089801008, 0.219086164, 2.568237924, 
    0.054330796, 0.597450037, 1.999999999, 2.601784687, 1.031812817, 
    0.146383739), month_tot = c(58.999999982, 58.999999982, 58.999999982, 
    58.999999982, 58.999999982, 58.999999982, 58.999999982, 58.999999982, 
    58.999999982, 58.999999982, 58.999999982, 58.999999982, 58.999999982, 
    58.999999982, 58.999999982, 58.999999982, 58.999999982, 58.999999982, 
    27.000000001, 27.000000001, 27.000000001, 27.000000001, 27.000000001, 
    27.000000001, 27.000000001, 27.000000001, 27.000000001, 27.000000001, 
    27.000000001, 8.999999999, 8.999999999, 8.999999999, 8.999999999, 
    8.999999999, 8.999999999, 8.999999999), prey_frq = c(29.1989395038234, 
    30.6991688313997, 0.0686501356141645, 0.00858733559584021, 
    9.36270136048353, 3.62201499093553, 6.20042535273911, 0.00439872711998605, 
    5.1841950219206, 2.45796822617362, 0.66203515613418, 0.0205421254299959, 
    0.000224301694983685, 5.52359295083771, 4.00735987071411, 
    0.244910400074718, 1.42908909196142, 1.30519661734735, 38.9175942726327, 
    8.71989362930667, 3.70370370356653, 13.7109630106033, 16.3914722030966, 
    10.062589803331, 6.86290285159767, 0.0212191074066215, 0.46563485553831, 
    0.332596325913608, 0.811430237006984, 28.535976936504, 0.603675511178186, 
    6.63833374518204, 22.2222222135802, 28.9087187476565, 11.4645868568294, 
    1.62648598906961), pos_label = c(85.4005302480883, 55.4514760804767, 
    40.0675665969698, 40.0289478613648, 35.3433035133251, 28.8509453376155, 
    23.9397251657782, 20.8373131258487, 18.2430162513284, 14.4219346272813, 
    12.8619329361274, 12.5206442953453, 12.5102610817828, 9.74835245551644, 
    4.98287604474054, 2.85674090934613, 2.01974116332806, 0.652598308673674, 
    80.5412028636837, 56.722458912714, 50.5106602462774, 41.8033268891925, 
    26.7521092823425, 13.5250782791287, 5.06233195166436, 1.6202709721622, 
    1.37684399068974, 0.977728399963794, 0.405715118503494, 85.732011531748, 
    71.1621853079069, 67.5411806797268, 53.1109027003457, 27.5454322197273, 
    7.3587794174843, 0.813242994534804), Type = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), levels = c("Pelagic", "Benthic", "Other"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -36L), groups = structure(list(
    Season = structure(1:3, levels = c("Pre-Hypoxic", "Peak-Hypoxic", 
    "Post-Hypoxic"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:18, 19:29, 30:36), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame" ), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df",  "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Also ran this line:

```
list <- c('Other' = 'none', 'Pelagic' = 'stripe', 'Benthic' = 'circle')
```

I have the following packages loaded:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library("RColorBrewer")
library(data.table)
library(ggsci)
library(ggpattern)
```

I factored and ordered the "Type" group because I want the legend in the following order: Pelagic, Benthic, Other.

Specifically, I would like to:

1. Have the pattern more clear in the legend. For example, have more lines (more than 1) for the "pelagic" group and more circles for the "benthic" group in the legend.
2. Add an outline(box) outside the legend pattern items (have a box/outline for the lines, one for the circles, and one for the blank ("other") group.
3. Remove the title "Type" for this legend while keeping the title "Prey Name" for the other legend.
4. Not extremely important, but is it possible to move the pattern legend while keeping the Prey Name legend where it is (moving the pattern to the "top" position for example). Or can I center/align the pattern ("Type") legend so it is centered (in the middle) over the Prey Name legend?

I have been trying to edit the legend for a few days now, but nothing I have tried has worked/improved it.

Any other suggestions on the aesthetics of this plot are welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- `face` isn't an argument, but `fontface` is in `geom_text` (it's `face` in theme, though)
- in `scale_pattern_manual`, you have `values = list`, then you included your list (not the variable, but the content) in that function. You don't need both. One or the other is sufficient.

I think the easiest way to make this all happen is to create three separate plots. The first will only have the pattern legend. The second will only have the color legend. The third won't have a legend. Finally, smash the pieces together. This is what this creates.

[image]

#### Type legend

I made several changes to make the `type` legend look as you described. In `ggplot`, I commented out the call for `fill`. In `geom_col_pattern` (or `bar + identity`), I added `fill` and `color`, along with reducing the scale factor (so you have many strips and dots in your legend). I also removed the call for `scale_fill_igv` and `guide`. Finally, I added `legend.margin` and `legend.title` to the call for `theme`. (I think that's everything.)

This gives you a legend with more prevalent pattern, with boxes around the patterns, and a method to center it over the other legend. The only thing that matters in this plot is the legend. That's the only part we'll keep.

[image]

```
# library(ggplot2) # redundant (this is in tidyverse)
# library(tidyverse) <--- moved last, so its functions have priority
library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(data.table)
library(ggsci)
library(ggpattern)
library(cowplot)    # get_legend(), plot_grid()
library(patchwork)  # blank plot: plot_spacer()
library(tidyverse)

#------------- for the pattern legend -------------
ggplot(try2, aes(Season, prey_frq, #fill = PreyName, 
                 pattern = Type), fill = "white") +
  geom_col_pattern(fill = "white", color = "black",
                   pattern_color = "black", pattern_angle = 45,
                   pattern_density = 0.04, pattern_spacing = 0.04,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.3) +
  geom_text(data = subset(try2, prey_frq > 3),
            aes(y = pos_label, label = PreyName), fontface = "bold", size = 7) + # <---- error here; fixed face to fontface
  scale_pattern_manual(values = list, name = "") +
  ggtitle("TITLE") +
  labs(x="Season", fill = "Prey Name", y = "Prey Biomass Consumed (%)") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face = "bold", family = "Arial", size=15),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = 1),
        # legend.title.align = 0.5,
        legend.margin = margin(t = .1, r = 15, b = 5, l = 15),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15, color = "black",
                                    margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x.top = element_text(size = 14, color = "black",
                                        margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 10, l = 0)),
        text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1,
                                   margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, angle = 0, vjust = 1.5, hjust = 0.5,
                                   margin = margin(t = 5, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0.2,"cm")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0.01)))
```

Now, extract the legend. If you don't call this immediately after, `last_plot()` won't work. (You can just assign the plot to an object and use the object name here.)

```
types = get_legend(last_plot())    # extract the legend
```

#### Color legend

Next, the color legend. The only real change here is the removal of the pattern legend. Starting with the original plot (not the plot for the other legend), I commented out the call for `pattern` in the `ggplot` call. I commented out the call for `scale_pattern_manual` and the call for `title` in `guides`.

```
#------------ color legend ------------
ggplot(try2, aes(Season, prey_frq, fill = PreyName,
                 # pattern = Type
)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(stat = "identity", pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_color = "black", pattern_angle = 45,
                   pattern_density = 0.04, pattern_spacing = 0.04,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) +
  geom_text(data = subset(try2, prey_frq>3),
            aes(y = pos_label, label = PreyName), 
            fontface = "bold", size = 4) +
  # scale_pattern_manual(values = list, name = "") +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal") + 
  ggtitle("TITLE") +
  labs(x="Season", fill = "Prey Name", y = "Prey Biomass Consumed (%)") + 
  scale_fill_igv(palette = "default") +
  guides(pattern = guide_legend(
    # title = "Type", 
    title.position = "top", label.position = "right", 
    label.hjust = 0.5, label.vjust = 1, override.aes = list(fill = "white"), order = 2),
    fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none", order = 1))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face = "bold", family = "Arial", size=15),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = 1),
        legend.title.align = 0.5,
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15, color = "black",
                                    margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x.top = element_text(size = 14, color = "black",
                                        margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 10, l = 0)),
        text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1,
                                   margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, angle = 0, vjust = 1.5, hjust = 0.5,
                                   margin = margin(t = 5, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0.2,"cm")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0.01)))
```

This is the plot.

[image]

Just like the last plot, you need to capture the legend.

```
prey = get_legend(last_plot())
```

Next, we'll combine the legends into one element. This is going to naturally center the two over each other.

```
(legs <- plot_grid(types, prey, plot_spacer() + theme_void(),
                   nrow = 2, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(.1, .6)))
```

[image]

#### No legend

Now, for your original plot. First, you don't want any legends. The easiest way to do this is to add `legend.position = "none"` to the call for `theme`. Everything else related to the legends needs to stay the same, so the plot renders correctly.

There were a few things I took the liberty of changing. One of the biggest issues with `ggplot` is the not-so-relative text. You can fix that with the function `rel()`. Additionally, with the text actually bold (it's not in your picture), it's blown out. I added `str_wrap` to `geom_text` to wrap the text. With the stripes, the black text was really swallowed up, so I tried white and other variations of light colors to see what worked. It seems like `yellow` does pretty well. (You can always change it.) I used the argument `lineheight` to bring wrapped text closer together. Finally, I assigned this plot to the object name `plt`.

```
# ----------- final plot ----- NO LEGEND -------------
ggplot(try2, aes(Season, prey_frq, fill = PreyName, pattern = Type)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(stat = "identity", pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_color = "black", pattern_angle = 45,
                   pattern_density = 0.04, pattern_spacing = 0.04,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) +
  geom_text(data = subset(try2, prey_frq>3),
            aes(y = pos_label, label = str_wrap(PreyName, 10)), 
            fontface = "bold", size = rel(4.5), color = "yellow",
            lineheight = .8) + # <---- error here; fixed face to fontface
  scale_pattern_manual(values = list, name = "") +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal") + 
  ggtitle("TITLE") +
  labs(x="Season", fill = "Prey Name", y = "Prey Biomass Consumed (%)") + 
  scale_fill_igv(palette = "default") +
  guides(pattern = guide_legend(
    # title = "Type", 
    title.position = "top", label.position = "right", 
    label.hjust = 0.5, label.vjust = 1, override.aes = list(fill = "white"), order = 2),
    fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none", order = 1))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face = "bold", family = "Arial", size=15),
        # legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = 1),
        # legend.title.align = 0.5,
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15, color = "black",
                                    margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x.top = element_text(size = 14, color = "black",
                                        margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 10, l = 0)),
        text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1,
                                   margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, angle = 0, vjust = 1.5, hjust = 0.5,
                                   margin = margin(t = 5, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0.2,"cm")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0.01))) -> plt
```

[image]

Alright, one step left. Put it all together. Depending on how you're going to use this and the size of your viewer pane, you may need to adjust the `rel_widths`.

```
plot_grid(plt, legs, ncol = 2, rel_widths = c(.8, .4))
```

[image]

Next, I've put all of the code together in one chunk to make it easier for you to collect it. (It's all the same code you see above.)

```
# library(ggplot2) # redundant
# library(tidyverse) <--- moved last, so it's functions have priority
library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(data.table)
library(ggsci)
library(ggpattern)
library(cowplot)    # get_legend(), plot_grid()
library(patchwork)  # blank plot: plot_spacer()
library(tidyverse)

#------------- for the pattern legend -------------
ggplot(try2, aes(Season, prey_frq, #fill = PreyName, 
                 pattern = Type), fill = "white") +
  geom_col_pattern(fill = "white", color = "black",
                   pattern_color = "black", pattern_angle = 45,
                   pattern_density = 0.04, pattern_spacing = 0.04,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.3) +
  geom_text(data = subset(try2, prey_frq > 3),
            aes(y = pos_label, label = PreyName), fontface = "bold", size = 7) + # <---- error here; fixed face to fontface
  scale_pattern_manual(values = list, name = "") +
  ggtitle("TITLE") +
  labs(x="Season", fill = "Prey Name", y = "Prey Biomass Consumed (%)") + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face = "bold", family = "Arial", size=15),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = 1),
        # legend.title.align = 0.5,
        legend.margin = margin(t = .1, r = 15, b = 5, l = 15),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15, color = "black",
                                    margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x.top = element_text(size = 14, color = "black",
                                        margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 10, l = 0)),
        text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1,
                                   margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, angle = 0, vjust = 1.5, hjust = 0.5,
                                   margin = margin(t = 5, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0.2,"cm")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0.01)))

types = get_legend(last_plot())

#------------ color legend ------------
ggplot(try2, aes(Season, prey_frq, fill = PreyName,
                 # pattern = Type
)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(stat = "identity", pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_color = "black", pattern_angle = 45,
                   pattern_density = 0.04, pattern_spacing = 0.04,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) +
  geom_text(data = subset(try2, prey_frq>3),
            aes(y = pos_label, label = PreyName), 
            fontface = "bold", size = 4) +
  # scale_pattern_manual(values = list, name = "") +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal") + 
  ggtitle("TITLE") +
  labs(x="Season", fill = "Prey Name", y = "Prey Biomass Consumed (%)") + 
  scale_fill_igv(palette = "default") +
  guides(pattern = guide_legend(
    # title = "Type", 
    title.position = "top", label.position = "right", 
    label.hjust = 0.5, label.vjust = 1, override.aes = list(fill = "white"), order = 2),
    fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none", order = 1))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "right", 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face = "bold", family = "Arial", size=15),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = 1),
        legend.title.align = 0.5,
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15, color = "black",
                                    margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x.top = element_text(size = 14, color = "black",
                                        margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 10, l = 0)),
        text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1,
                                   margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, angle = 0, vjust = 1.5, hjust = 0.5,
                                   margin = margin(t = 5, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0.2,"cm")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0.01)))

prey = get_legend(last_plot())

(legs <- plot_grid(types, prey, plot_spacer() + theme_void(),
                   nrow = 2, ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(.1, .6)))


# ----------- final plot ----- NO LEGEND -------------
ggplot(try2, aes(Season, prey_frq, fill = PreyName, pattern = Type)) +
  geom_bar_pattern(stat = "identity", pattern_fill = "black",
                   pattern_color = "black", pattern_angle = 45,
                   pattern_density = 0.04, pattern_spacing = 0.04,
                   pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) +
  geom_text(data = subset(try2, prey_frq>3),
            aes(y = pos_label, label = str_wrap(PreyName, 10)), 
            fontface = "bold", size = rel(4.5), color = "yellow",
            lineheight = .8) + # <---- error here; fixed face to fontface
  scale_pattern_manual(values = list, name = "") +
  theme(legend.direction = "horizontal") + 
  ggtitle("TITLE") +
  labs(x="Season", fill = "Prey Name", y = "Prey Biomass Consumed (%)") + 
  scale_fill_igv(palette = "default") +
  guides(pattern = guide_legend(
    # title = "Type", 
    title.position = "top", label.position = "right", 
    label.hjust = 0.5, label.vjust = 1, override.aes = list(fill = "white"), order = 2),
    fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pattern = "none", order = 1))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "none", 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face = "bold", family = "Arial", size=15),
        # legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = 1),
        # legend.title.align = 0.5,
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15, color = "black",
                                    margin = margin(t = 0, r = 10, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x.top = element_text(size = 14, color = "black",
                                        margin = margin(t = 0, r = 0, b = 10, l = 0)),
        text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, angle = 0, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1,
                                   margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", 
                                   size = 13, angle = 0, vjust = 1.5, hjust = 0.5,
                                   margin = margin(t = 5, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold"),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length = unit(0.2,"cm")) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0,0.01))) -> plt

plot_grid(plt, legs, ncol = 2, rel_widths = c(.8, .4))
```

Comment: wow ! thank you so much for such a detailed answer! this is exactly what I was trying to do. I didn't think of making all these separate and then putting them together. Thanks for the suggestion on the labels font color, I do think the yellow looks better since the labels stand out more instead of getting blended in with the patterns. Thanks again!!

Comment: I deleted the first few lines of my answer about errors in your theme. When I first ran your code, I had a bunch of errors. However, it was because several `tidyverse` functions were overwritten from other libraries. I'm pretty sure that there was nothing wrong with your theme code. Sorry about that!

Comment: good to know that it wasn't my code, I wasn't sure if there was a typo in my question because things were working fine on my end (not getting any error messages). I will keep in mind your suggestion of loading tidyverse last because I have run into issues before when packages have conflicts